# find last occurrence of `/` in file path in coldfusion

Tags: function, coldfusion

In Coldfusion, I tried to find the function to find the index value of last occurrence of `/` in file path so that file name after `/` is picked up. can any body suggest me the solution. I want to retrieve file name from a file path.

Comment: I know nothing of CF, but one way I do this elsewhere is 1. reverse string, stringleft till /, 3 reverse string.... There are probably much faster and elegant ways.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `GetFileFromPath(filepath)`. It returns the file name from a given path.

```
<cfset fileName = GetFileFromPath(filepath)>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could either use `listLast()` to get the fragment of the string you want directly:

```
filePart = listLast(fullPath, "/\");
```

Or you could simply use java.lang.String's [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method to approach it exactly the way you describe.

However I'd just use `listLast()`.

Comment: Actually scratch that: I'd just do what @coldfusiondevshop suggested!

Answer (score 0):

Work great. change the code to use `.` to get the extension of a file for create a archive file name to back up old version.

Added the code `listLast(form.Document_File_Nm, ".">` to the below plus added the period back in to the filename.

```
<cfset ArchiveFileName = mid(form.Document_File_Nm,1,len(form.Document_File_Nm)-4) & '_' & trim(ATTUID) & '_' & DateFormat(now(),'YYYYMMDD') & TimeFormat(now(),'HHMMSS') & '.' & listLast(form.Document_File_Nm, ".")>
```